# How to chain plain Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML=data();
```

I would like to do something (url/split) after this code has finished:

```
$(data).find('a').prop('href', function(_, href){
    url = href.split('/');          
    return href.replace(url[2], 'someUrl');

});
```

How do I chain the two codes together? I tried:

```
document.body.innerHTML=data().end().find('a').prop('href', function(_, href){
    url = href.split('/');          
    return href.replace(url[2], 'someUrl');

})
```

doesn't work, tried some other variations with no luck.

Comment: Why are you trying to chain them in the first place? I can tell you how but it just makes your code inconsistent.

Comment: run the jquery inside document.ready

Comment: Please clarify what `data` is and provide any other related functions (in case `data` is a function)

Comment: Hi all, data is a complete website (<html></html>) which Im screen scraping. Im trying to attach the Jquery split/replace to the plain javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
document.body.innerHTML = $(data).find('a').prop('href', function(_, href){
    url = href.split('/');          
    return href.replace(url[2], 'someUrl');
}).wrap("<div>").parent().html();
```

I'm not exactly sure of the difference between your `data()` and `$(data)` because you mix them but they are totally different.

Anyways, the result of `.prop(name, func)` is the selected element from before. So when your last call in the chain is `.prop(name, func)`, you're trying to set `document.body.innerHTML` as a jQuery object...basically: `document.body.innerHTML = $("element");`. But I think you're trying to get the `data`s HTML, so that's what the extra chaining I added should do.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me..don't know why. I get only one insignificant img from the website Im screen scraping(=data)

Comment: I already had this code in the past, something like this: $('html').append(data).find('a').prop.....and so one. Did not work for me with some websites so I switch to plain javascript document.body.innerHTML which was better but now Im missing the split function...

Comment: Well `$('html').append(data)` is already a bad idea. You shouldn't be appending elements on the `<html>` tag...do it with the `<body>` tag. That's why `document.body` works "better" - it should've been `$("body")` in the first place. Also, I'm not sure you can append a full HTML document into the `<body>` element. You'd need to get the `<body>`'s contents and only append that. Anyways, can you please update your question with more of your jQuery code that this applies to? And also provide a complete (simplified) example of what would be in the `data` variable?

Comment: document.documentElement.innerHTML seems to work thanks for pointing in the right direction.